# CoreBluetooth CBMutableCharacteristic properties vs permissions

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm in the process of updating an iOS app that needs to act as a Bluetooth peripheral.  I've been referencing Apple's "[Transferring Data Between Bluetooth Low Energy Devices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices)" sample code and I'm confused about the [properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmutablecharacteristic/1519087-properties) vs the [permissions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmutablecharacteristic/1518891-permissions) of a CBMutableCharacteristic.  Here's how Apple's sample code inits an instance of CBMutableCharacteristic:

```
let transferCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: TransferService.characteristicUUID,
                                                 properties: [.notify, .writeWithoutResponse],
                                                 value: nil,
                                                 permissions: [.readable, .writeable])
```

The docs for permissions offer the following explanation:

> When you initialize a new mutable characteristic, you set the read,
> write, and encryption permissions for the characteristic’s value.
> Setting the read and write permissions for a characteristic’s value is
> different from specifying the read and write properties for a
> characteristic’s value.

So far, so good.  But here's where I'm getting confused:

> When you specify the read and write properties, the client (a central)
> inspects the read and write permissions of the characteristic’s value.
> When you specify the read and write permissions for a characteristic’s
> value, you set the permissions for the server (the peripheral) to
> allow the type of read or write specified by the characteristic’s
> properties. Therefore, when you initialize a mutable characteristic,
> you need to specify read or write properties and their corresponding
> permissions.

I've probably read that at least a dozen times and I'm still not sure that I understand it!  If there are any Core Bluetooth experts out there who can clarify this for me, I'd certainly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `permissions` specify *what can be done* to the characteristic -

- Can it be written?
- Can it be read?

The `properties` specify *how it can be done* -

- If writes are permitted, can you use *write with response*? *write without response*?
- If reading is permitted, can you use *notify*? *indicate*? *read*?

The example in your question specifies a characteristic that is both readable and writable.

Permissions: `[.readable, .writeable]`

Reads are performed via notify (The peripheral notifies the Central when the value changes).

Writes are performed without a response (The peripheral does not provide a response to the central indicating whether the write was successful or not).

Properties: `[.notify, .writeWithoutResponse]`